# iOS 11 not displaying media control

Tags: ios, mediaplayer, control-center

When I play media in iOS 11 (e.g. spotify), media control doesn't recognize it and show it on my lock screen or in control center.

If I do a hard reset, the problem goes away temporarily.

I am using an iPhone 6S (64GB) and running iOS 11.0.2.

UPDATE: the problem has magically dissapeared on my device, though i'll leave the question up since I know others might have this problem.